# Is a line considered a face in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Is a line considered a face in graph theory?

For example just a straight line point to point.

0-------------------------0

Comment: Please try to make your titles more descriptive. Almost all your questions are titled "<Branch of Math> Question".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is an edge.  There is one face in your graph though: the unbounded or infinite face, sometimes denoted $f_\infty$.

Comment: With a single line as your graph, is the degree of the infinite face 1 (definining the degree of a face as the number of edges encountered during a walk around the face)?

Comment: The degree of $f_\infty$ in this case is 2, since your walk uses the edge twice to return to the starting vertex.  Note that the sum of all the degrees of the faces in a planar graph is always twice the number of edges.